# Error message is coming while configuring provisional profile

Tags: ios, xcode

An error popup is coming while configuring provisional profile. The error message is:

> "you have no permission to read/write project.pbxproj file"

Actually the working project was handed over to me. So I am configuring the same provisional profile which was used for earlier configuration. And also I am using the same Mac with different account. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: apparently, you have "no permission to read/write project.pbxproj file". Most likely, the "different account" is the culprit here

Comment: Can you chmod or chown the `project.pbxproj` file? On a Mac, you can open a terminal and run those commands